Equivalence Classes of vector fields on $S^{n}$
Suppose for a compact smooth manifold $M$, for 2 tangent vector fields, define $X\sim Y$ iff there exists a $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphism  $\psi\colon M\rightarrow M$ s.t.
$$X = \mathrm{d}\psi(Y).$$
This defines equivalence classes on $\Gamma(TM)$, is there any description about it?
If the question when $M$ is compact is not solved, what about when $M$ is $S^{n}$?

A necessary condition is that $X$ and $Y$ has the same number of zeroes, and the index at each zero is the same, but I don't know if it's sufficient.

The diffeomorphism group of a manifold $\text{Diff}(M)$ can be given the structure of an infinite dimensional Lie group, and its Lie algebra is $\Gamma(TM)$ with the Lie bracket of vector fields. The adjoint action of $\text{Diff}(M)$ on $\Gamma(TM)$ is just $\text{Ad}\psi(X)=\psi*X$. So, the equivalence class of $X\in\Gamma(TM)$ is the orbit of $X$ under the adjoint action. The structure of such a space seems, in general, quite difficult to analyse.

The orbit space will be diffeomorphic to $\text{Diff}(M)/\text{Diff}_X(M)$, where $\text{Diff}_X(M)$ is the isotropy group of $X$.

If $X\sim Y$ then a diffeomorphism of $M$ carries the set of zeroes of $X$ to the set of zeroes of $Y$. Note that every closed subset of $M$ can be realized as the set of zeroes of a smooth vector field. But even in the case $M=S^1$ this is not the full story. All in all, expecting a description is very unrealistic.

@MoisheKohan Thank you! what if ＄X$ has only finite number of zeroes?

If you also assume that zeroes are nondegenerate and $M=S^1$ then the number of zeroes is the only invariant. But already for $S^2$ this is no longer the case and for the given number of zeroes you have continuum of equivalence classes. Things are a bit more predictable if you assume that $X$ is a "Morse-Smale" vector field, then you get finiteness. But the classification is difficult even in dimension 2 and is out of reach in higher dimensions. If you are interested, consider reading for instance "Topological classification of simple Morse Bott functions on surfaces" by Martinez-Alfaro et al.

@MoisheKohan Thank you so much! I'm not familiar with differential topology and Morse theory, I'll read that.
